# Is String thread safe like StringBuffer or not?

Tags: java, string, thread-safety, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

In Java, as stated in the javadoc:

- The `StringBuffer` class is thread-safe.
- The `StringBuilder` class is NOT thread-safe

But is the `String` class considered as thread-safe or not ?

Comment: For every c# class there is a msdn page which contains paragraph titled "Thread Safety". Here's a link for String class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.100).aspx . Please read official documentation before asking questions like this one in the future.

Answer (score 3):

According to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

> Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are
>   created. String buffers support mutable strings. Because String
>   objects are immutable they can be shared.

Because Strings are immutable, they are thread safe.

Comment: Immutability does not necessarily mean Thread Safe, as demonstrated in https://dzone.com/articles/do-immutability-really-means.